# Device Id never show to new contacts and don't receive notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I implemented the library, in version 8.0, with react-native, I can see the data locally, but it is not registered in "All contacts". I can see the data from: getContactKey, getSystemToken, getAttributes, isPushEnabled = true.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    MarketingCloudSdk.init(this, MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
        .setApplicationId("My aplication id")
        .setAccessToken("My acess token")
        .setSenderId("my sender id from firebase")
        .setMarketingCloudServerUrl("my url server/")
        .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(R.drawable.notification_icon,
            new NotificationManager.NotificationLaunchIntentProvider() {
              @Override public PendingIntent getNotificationPendingIntent(Context context,
                  NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
                if (notificationMessage == null || notificationMessage.url() == null || notificationMessage.url().isEmpty()) {
                  return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, new Random().nextInt(),
                      context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName()),
                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
                } else {
                  return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, new Random().nextInt(),
                      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(notificationMessage.url())),
                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
                }
              }
            }, null))
        .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
        .build(this), initializationStatus -> Log.e("INIT", initializationStatus.toString()));


SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
//OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new SSLPinnerFactory());
```

}

After login I call these functions

```
  await MCReactModule.enablePush();
  await MCReactModule.setContactKey(email)
```

After this implementation, I do the following:

- I create the emails in Data Extensions that I want to receive the push
- In Mobile Push I create a new message and send it to that created email group
- After the submission is complete, I do not receive any pushes

Note: All configured emails went through the app's flow of setting the contactKey.

Could anyone help me with this topic, please?

Im testing in android.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). You will need to [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/412326/edit) your question to include more details.

Comment: @TusharJadav, I improved my question a little, is it better this way?

Answer (score 0):

After a long time racking my brain over this... I discovered that a character in my "acessToken" was wrong, instead of a "j" there was an "i" and I hadn't noticed because everything else was right...